# ggplot2 annotate using a measure unit other than the axis variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I've got the following code

```
d1=data.frame(a=c(4,5,6,7),b=as.Date(c('2005-12-31','2006-12-31','2007-12-31','2008-12-31'),"%Y-%m-%d"))
a = ggplot(d1,aes(x=b,y=a)) + geom_line()
a + annotate('text',x=as.Date('2006-12-31','%Y-%m-%d'),y=5.5,label='blah')
```

But annotating the graph is really clunky. I'd like to be able to specify the x axis using percentage of axis (for example) or inches or something else. Is this possible and how would I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option, I think, is to post-process the graph using grid. You'll need to expose the viewports and navigate to the plot panel, and there you have access to all grid units. Following [Paul Murrell's example:](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/ggplotSlider/ggplotSlider.html)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

qplot(1:10, rnorm(10))
# grid.force() # doesn't seem necessary?
# grid.ls()

downViewport("panel.3-4-3-4")
grid.text(label = "Some text", x = unit(0,"inch"),hjust=0)
grid.text(label = "Some text", x = unit(0.5,"npc"),hjust=0.5)
upViewport(0)
```

Comment: thanks @baptiste. This works for me. Great link to understand how to use grid with ggplot too.

Answer (score 1):

The package 'scales' includs a ton of formatter options: e.g. to format the y-axis in your example to percent use "scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)"

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

d1=data.frame(a=c(4,5,6,7),b=as.Date(c('2005-12-31','2006-12-31','2007-12-31','2008-12-   31'),"%Y-%m-%d"))
a = ggplot(d1,aes(x=b,y=a)) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) 
a + annotate('text',x=as.Date('2006-12-31','%Y-%m-%d'),y=5.5,label='blah')
```

Have a look at the [ggplot docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/scale_continuous.html) as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply @hvolimeier. I was looking to keep the format in this case just change the specifying units, but I agree that scales is an incredibly useful package.